# How to display the github code in my website without gist

Tags: github, github-api

I want to show my [GitHub code](https://github.com/gurusabarish/python-programs/blob/master/Basic%20programs/arr.py) in my website. But I need style it with css. So I cant use GitHub gist.

**Is there is a way to display my GitHub code or markdown to website ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your raw code is located at the below link which is available in text format.

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurusabarish/python-programs/master/Basic%20programs/arr.py

You can load the data using `AJAX` and style it in your website.

Thank you